# Converted my own Keras CNN model to TensorFlow Lite. Detection results in TensorFlow Lite Demo App wrong

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I am working with a Keras CNN for image classification I built myself. Detection results on my PC machine are fine for now (about 290 out of 300 test images detected correctly). Now I need to get my model running on an Android phone. I installed the [TFLite Demo App](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/demo_android) on my phone. So far it works well with the preinstalled model as well as with some random pretrained models I found online. Sadly, if I convert the model do TFLite it will show wrong detection results.

Now to convert my Keras (.h5-file) to TFLite (.tflite-file) I followed the description on the official [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api) website, using this code:

```
# Convert to TensorFlow Lite model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

As I said above, the just created keras-model (`keras_file`) I used to convert to TFLite works perfectly fine on testing, but the TFLite-model does not. To be exact. For testing purposes there are currently 4 possible categories to detect. In 3 out of 4 cases the app will show me a wrong detection result, saying it is 100% certain. I thought there could be a problem with the label file I created. But there is no scheme to find (like maybe the order of the strings in the file are wrong or something). So I am almost certain that the label-file is OK.

Now what I did on the Android app:

- (As mentioned in the [description](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/demo_android)) change the classifier to `ImageClassifierFloatInception`.
- Create the label-file containing 4 strings for my 4 categories
- Change the image size
- Change the return value of `getNumBytesPerChannel()` to 4, to match my category-count

Specs:

- Windows 10
- Tf-nightly-gpu 1.13.0a20181125 (TensorFlow-gpu 1.12.0 won't support the convert method)
- Galaxy S6 on Android 7.0

Am I missing something? If you need more information I am happy to provide.

Stephan

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with your `convertBitmaptoByteBuffer()` function, or maybe with your `.tflite` model.